# Reducing time series data from half hour to hourly in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with smart meter data which is in half-hourly resolution. Due to the sheer volume of data I am trying to reduce from half-hourly resolution to hourly resolution. In doing so I am attempting to sum the consumption between two half-hourly measurements. The issue is I also have catagorical data in my data frame which I lose when using xts. This is what my data looks like:

```
> head(test1)
      LCLid stdorToU            DateTime KWH.hh..per.half.hour.   Acorn Acorn_grouped
1 MAC000002      Std 2012-10-12 00:30:00                      0 ACORN-A      Affluent
2 MAC000002      Std 2012-10-12 01:00:00                      0 ACORN-A      Affluent
3 MAC000002      Std 2012-10-12 01:30:00                      0 ACORN-A      Affluent
4 MAC000002      Std 2012-10-12 02:00:00                      0 ACORN-A      Affluent
5 MAC000002      Std 2012-10-12 02:30:00                      0 ACORN-A      Affluent
6 MAC000002      Std 2012-10-12 03:00:00                      0 ACORN-A      Affluent
```

Here is the code I have been attempting to use and the result I get.

```
test1 <- read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
test1$DateTime <- ymd_hms(test1$DateTime)
test1$KWH.hh..per.half.hour. <- as.numeric(test1$KWH.hh..per.half.hour.)
test2 <- xts(test1$KWH.hh..per.half.hour., test1$DateTime)
head(test2)
period.apply(test2, endpoints(test2, "hours"), sum)

> period.apply(test2, endpoints(test2, "hours"), sum)
                     [,1]
2012-10-12 00:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 01:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 02:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 03:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 04:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 05:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 06:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 07:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 08:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 09:30:00 0.000
2012-10-12 10:30:00 0.000
```

Ideally, I need a data set exactly as my original (test1), just half the size aggregated to hourly frequency rather than half-hourly. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a grouping column, and then sum by group.

```
# create grouped column
test1$grouped_time = lubridate::floor_date(test1$DateTime, unit = "hour")
# (use ceiling_date instead if you want to round the half hours up instead of down)

# sum by group
library(dplyr)
test2 = test1 %>%
  group_by(grouped_time, LCLid, stdorToU, Acorn, Acorn_grouped) %>%
  summarize(KWH.hh.per.hour = sum(KWH.hh..per.half.hour.))
```

There are many alternatives to `dplyr` at the [Sum by Group R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061), in case you want to look at more options.

Note that this will sum the KWH column for each unique combination of the other columns in `group_by()`. If some of those can change, like if `stdorToU` or the `ACORN` values might change from an hour to the next half hour but you still want the rows combined, you need to move that column out of `group_by` and into `summarize`, and specify which value to keep, e.g.

```
# if ACORN can change and you want to keep the first one
test2 = test1 %>%
  group_by(grouped_time, LCLid, stdorToU, Acorn_grouped) %>%
  summarize(KWH.hh.per.hour = sum(KWH.hh..per.half.hour.),
            ACORN = first(ACORN))
```

Comment: Gregor, worked fine, although interestingly for every hour that is 00:00:00 this time doesnt exist in the data frame, just the date. Almost like R sees that time as zero. This wasnt the case before running "grouped_by". Any thought's why?

Comment: Huh, I can't replicate that. If you share a little bit of your data using `dput`, like `dput(droplevels(test1[1:10, ]))` I can hopefully see what you're seeing. (Pick a different subset than the first 10 rows to make sure a `00:00:00` example is included)

Comment: I have commented in an answer below (sorry I wasn't sure where to add such a long response). The variable name has changed since after getting it to work I used the whole data set rather than the smaller test set

Comment: It's good practice to include some `dput` in your question, that's the best place for it.

Comment: But, I think the answer is *it's just printing behavior*. With `x = c(1, 2, 3.5)`, if you print a subset of `x` that has only  integers, they will print without a decimal: `x[1:2]` gives `1 2`. But if you print a subset that has a decimal, they all print with decimals, `x[2:3]` gives `2.0 3.5`. Same thing happens with the datetimes - if you print a subset that is all `00:00:00` in the time component, it will be omitted. But if any of the datetimes has a non-zero time component, they will all be printed.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I am new to datascience so great to have people like you clear things like this up for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
> head(sm_2013_tof)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   grouped_time, LCLid, stdorToU, Acorn [6]
  grouped_time        LCLid     stdorToU Acorn   Acorn_grouped KWH.hh.per.hour
  <dttm>              <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>                   <dbl>
1 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000146 ToU      ACORN-L Adversity               0.155
2 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000147 ToU      ACORN-F Comfortable             0.276
3 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000158 ToU      ACORN-H Comfortable             0.152
4 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000165 ToU      ACORN-E Affluent                0.401
5 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000170 ToU      ACORN-F Comfortable             0.64 
6 2013-01-01 00:00:00 MAC000173 ToU      ACORN-E Affluent                0.072
>
```

here is the now hourly data after grouping.

If i make this as.data.frame you see the 00:00:00 disappears

`sm_short_2013 <- as.data.frame(sm_2013_tof)`

```
> head(sm_short_2013)
  grouped_time     LCLid stdorToU   Acorn Acorn_grouped KWH.hh.per.hour
1   2013-01-01 MAC000146      ToU ACORN-L     Adversity           0.155
2   2013-01-01 MAC000147      ToU ACORN-F   Comfortable           0.276
3   2013-01-01 MAC000158      ToU ACORN-H   Comfortable           0.152
4   2013-01-01 MAC000165      ToU ACORN-E      Affluent           0.401
5   2013-01-01 MAC000170      ToU ACORN-F   Comfortable           0.640
6   2013-01-01 MAC000173      ToU ACORN-E      Affluent           0.072
```

```
> dput(droplevels(sm_short_2013[1:10, ]))
structure(list(grouped_time = structure(c(1356998400, 1356998400, 
1356998400, 1356998400, 1356998400, 1356998400, 1356998400, 1356998400, 
1356998400, 1356998400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    LCLid = c("MAC000146", "MAC000147", "MAC000158", "MAC000165", 
    "MAC000170", "MAC000173", "MAC000186", "MAC000187", "MAC000193", 
    "MAC000194"), stdorToU = c("ToU", "ToU", "ToU", "ToU", "ToU", 
    "ToU", "ToU", "ToU", "ToU", "ToU"), Acorn = c("ACORN-L", 
    "ACORN-F", "ACORN-H", "ACORN-E", "ACORN-F", "ACORN-E", "ACORN-E", 
    "ACORN-L", "ACORN-D", "ACORN-D"), Acorn_grouped = c("Adversity", 
    "Comfortable", "Comfortable", "Affluent", "Comfortable", 
    "Affluent", "Affluent", "Adversity", "Affluent", "Affluent"
    ), KWH.hh.per.hour = c(0.155, 0.276, 0.152, 0.401, 0.64, 
    0.072, 0.407, 0.554, 0.725, 0.158)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```